# Computing averages for a group of neighboring points in a line

Tags: python, average

I am trying to compute the average for a group of neighboring points in an array that I can easily move around. I've been advised to define a vector called a "dither" of integers from for example, 5 to 15. Heres the code I have right now:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.arange(0,10,.05)
wave = np.sin(x)

noise = np.random.normal(0,.05,200)
y = noise + wave
noise2 = np.random.normal(0,.05,200)
y2 = noise2 + wave
noise3 = np.random.normal(0,.05,200)
y3 = noise3 + wave


y_avg = (np.array(y) + np.array(y2) + np.array(y3)) / 3

for i in range(5, 15):
    mean = np.mean(y_avg)
print mean


plt.plot(x, y, color = 'red', label= 'line 1')
plt.plot(x, y2, color = 'pink', label = 'line 2')
plt.plot(x, y3, color = 'magenta', label = 'line 3')
plt.plot(x, y_avg, color = 'blue', label = 'average')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Is there a better way to do this that involves indexing the data vector/how do I do that?

Comment: Is your solution insufficient?

Comment: later on I'm going to have to use a center point and change the window size, so I've been advised to index it differently than I am right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slicing of the vector:

```
mean = np.mean(y_avg[5:15])
```

If you want a mid point, this works for even sized windows:

```python
def mean_slice(midp, size, array):
    slice_index = [midp - (size/2), midp + (size/2)]
    # Remove out of bounds indexes
    slice_index = [i if i > 0 else 0 for i in slice_index]
    slice_index = [i if i < len(array) else 0 for i in slice_index]
    return np.mean(array[slice(*slice_index)])

print mean_slice(1, 4, a)
>>>1.0
```

Comment: When I use "mean = np.mean(y_avg[4:5:])" it prints a value of 0.2902 as my average which cannot be correct since the y value of the graph is negative the whole time. Is there something wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Your y_avg array is positive at slice 4:5

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Thanks for your help. One more thing that is confusing me is why I get different values for 
`
    #calculating mean through np.mean
    y_avg = (np.array(y) + np.array(y2) + np.array(y3)) / 3
    print "mean calculation1", np.mean(y_avg[2:6])


#calculating mean through midpoint + size
def mean_slice(midpoint, size, array):
    slice_index = [midpoint - (size/2), midpoint + (size/2)]
    return np.mean(array[slice(*slice_index)])
print "mean calculation2", mean_slice(4,2, y_avg)
`code`
This is the result:
mean calculation1 0.172668616537
mean calculation2 0.204097947827

Comment: Sorry about my formatting. I basically have my original method of calculating average and then the slicing method you gave me, and they're showing different values for a range of 2-6.

Comment: They are just slicing slightly different places. To check just print out the slice in both methods. I think changing this line may fix it [midp - (size/2) - 1, midp + (size/2) - 1 ]

Comment: Ah, got it. I made a stupid mistake, read the window size incorrectly. Thanks for your help!